# Loading OpenSSL custom engine via openssl.conf file shows error

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine

I have a simple openssl engine that I want to load into OpenSSL via `openssl.conf` file. I have install `openssl-1.1.1c` from source using the following configuration setting,

> ./config --prefix=/opt/openssl -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF --openssldir=/opt/openssl

After installation `$openssl version` shows the following,

```
ss@ss:~$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
```

After that, I change `openssl.conf` like the following,

```
openssl_conf = openssl_def

[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
rsa-engine-new = rsa_section

[rsa_section]
engine_id = rsa-engine-new
```

Upon make those changes, `openssl engine` command shows the following,

```
ss@ss:/opt/openssl$ openssl engine
rsa-engine-new
(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
(rsa-engine-new) engine for testing 1
139904801769216:error:260AB089:engine routines:ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string:invalid cmd name:crypto/engine/eng_ctrl.c:255:
139904801769216:error:260BC066:engine routines:int_engine_configure:engine configuration error:crypto/engine/eng_cnf.c:141:section=rsa_section, name=oid_section, value=new_oids
139904801769216:error:0E07606D:configuration file routines:module_run:module initialization error:crypto/conf/conf_mod.c:177:module=engines, value=engine_section, retcode=-1
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: You may have some errors in the source code of your RSA engine. Focus on the first error message.

Comment: @DaniGrosu, thanks for the reply. With my engine, I'm only trying to provide description service. I was wondering if there is a set of common functionality that is needed to be implemented in the OpenSSL engine even If my intention is to only provide a decryption service with the engine? I guess I am asking if there is a common structure skeleton of the OpenSSL engine?

Comment: @DaniGrosu, Can you please provide the basic structure of an RSA engine? I followed the same structure from [openssl/engines/e_dasync.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/engines/e_dasync.c). Here is my basic Engine structure [rsa-engine.c](https://pastebin.com/EQfpF7cm). Did I added everything or Do I need to add `!ENGINE_set_destroy_function(e, dasync_destroy)`
 `!ENGINE_set_init_function(e, dasync_init)`
 `!ENGINE_set_finish_function(e, dasync_finish)` too?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from the OpenSSL mail list.

What happens is, I was putting the new configuration at the beginning of the `openssl.cnf` file. Therefore, I have the remnants of main openssl config.

Then I move the following section at the end of the `openssl.cnf` file

```
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
rsa-engine-new = rsa_section

[rsa_section]
engine_id = rsa-engine-new
dynamic_path = (PATH_TO_OPENSSL)/lib/engines-1.1/rsa-engine-new.so
```

And the engine loads without any error,

```
$openssl engine
(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
(rsa-engine-new) engine for testing 1
```